# MYSQL - Select total amount of 3 joined table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

table a => id, name

table b => id, id_a, amount

table c => id, id_a, amount

How can I select table a and the total amount from table b, and table c?

I already have tried:

```
SELECT a.`name`, SUM(b.`amount`) AS Total
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.`id` = b.`id_a`
UNION
SELECT a.`name`, SUM(c.`amount`) AS Total
FROM a
RIGHT JOIN c ON a.`id` = c.`id_a`
GROUP BY a.`id`
```

But it shows multiple records from table a where there is id_a value in both table b and table c.

FYI: if table a is inserted, so table b or table c or both table b and table c will be inserted the detail. So there is no possible table a has no detail in table a or table b

here is the example data

**table a:**

```
id | name
1 | name 1
2 | name 2
```

**table b:**

```
id | id_a | amount
1 | 1 | 300
2 | 1 | 200
```

**table c:**

```
id | id_a | amount
1 | 1 | 200
2 | 1 | 100
3 | 2 | 300
4 | 2 | 100
```

**Preferred Result:**

```
name | amount
name 1 | 800
name 2 | 400
```

**UPDATE THE ANSWER => Thanks to @Jens**

```
SELECT d.NAME, SUM(d.Total) FROM (
SELECT a.id AS id , a.`name` AS NAME, SUM(b.`amount`) AS Total
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.`id` = b.`id_a`
GROUP BY a.`id`
UNION
SELECT a.`id` AS id, a.`name`, SUM(c.`amount`) AS Total
FROM a
RIGHT JOIN c ON a.`id` = c.`id_a`
GROUP BY a.`id`
) AS d
GROUP BY d.`id`
```

**ANOTHER ANSWER FROM @Alex IS WORKING TOO AND SIMPLER
Thanks to both @Jens and @Alex. It's increase my knowledge**

Comment: you `group by` only works on the last select..

Comment: if i remove it, it only retrieve the first record of table a and the total amount. So it only retrieve 1 record. If i put it on both query, it will show redundant record of table a but, with different total amount of table b and table c

Comment: What is your preferred result? can you explain further?

Comment: @Edrich i already update the question and mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT a.name, sum(b.amount), sum(c.amount)
FROM a
JOIN b on a.id = b.id_a
JOIN c on a.id = c.id_a
GROUP BY a.id
```

not sure about the relations, but you can replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN if that's your case.

**UPDATE**

This should be working:

```
SELECT a.name as "name", sum(d.amount) as "amount"
FROM a
JOIN (SELECT id_a, amount FROM b UNION ALL SELECT id_a, amount FROM c) as d
on d.id_a = a.id
group by a.name
```

This yields the following results:

```
name1   |    800
name2   |    400
```

Comment: it's retrieve 2 rows (what i preferred), but the total amount is wrong

Comment: @SteakMalang I have updated the answer, could you please try it now? Although I have just seen that this is MySQL and I have done it in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select d.name, sum(d.total) from (
SELECT a.id as id , a.`name` as name, b.`amount` AS Total
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.`id` = b.`id_a`
UNION
SELECT a.id as id a.`name`, c.`amount` AS Total
FROM a
RIGHT JOIN c ON a.`id` = c.`id_a`
) as d
GROUP BY d.`id`
```

**UPDATED:**

```
SELECT d.NAME, SUM(d.Total) FROM (
SELECT a.id AS id , a.`name` AS NAME, SUM(b.`amount`) AS Total
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.`id` = b.`id_a`
GROUP BY a.`id`
UNION
SELECT a.`id` AS id, a.`name`, SUM(c.`amount`) AS Total
FROM a
RIGHT JOIN c ON a.`id` = c.`id_a`
GROUP BY a.`id`
) AS d
GROUP BY d.`id`
```

Comment: See my preferred result in my question. i just try your query, and the result for name 2 is correct (400) but name 1 total amount is 600. It should be 800

Comment: @SteakMalang Can you check which records you get in both subqueries for name 1?

Comment: Hi, already update the question and post the answer based on your query. Thanks

Comment: @Alex answer is working too and it's simpler. Thanks to both of you